# How to convert Flutter Mobile app to Web App

Tags: flutter, web, mobile, migration

is there any way to convert my mobile app to a web app in flutter?
My final goal is to run my mobile app as a web app.
I followed a tutorial but I was blocked because I got this error when i added flutter_web_test:any

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1.Enable web support by running:

```
flutter config --enable-web
```

2.Now, if you want to create a new project you can run

```
flutter create project_name
```

or if you want to migrate your existing one to web, run

```
flutter create .
```

3.Check connected devices by running:

```
flutter devices
```

4.Run your app in chrome by running:

```
flutter run -d chrome
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, when i followed what you mentioned i got this error;
the chrome page is launched but it didn't show anything.

Comment: check you have used any native packages that does not have web support

Comment: Actually I have firebase module, I configured it for android, do you think I have to reconfigure it from start to web app or I can just add the web configuration with the one i have now?